# ZendFramework 500 error with enabled mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework

i've moved project to xampp. I have enabled mod_rewrite.so, but htaccess wont revrite...

my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
```

httpd-xammp file:

```
Alias /iman "c:/xampp/htdocs/boilerplate/htdocs"
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs/boilerplate/htdocs">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

when i remove htaccess file page work, but firendly url dont work ofcourse.

curiosity: when i put into htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com/
```

it still wont work.

Comment: It could be helpful to add access_log and error_log.

Comment: i add

# suppress PHP errors from displaying in the browser
php_flag display_startup_errors on
php_flag display_errors on
php_flag html_errors on

# log PHP errors to a file
php_flag log_errors on
php_value error_reporting 32767
php_value error_log "log.txt"

and nothing was happend... any log, any new error...

Comment: I think he's asking to show the contents of your error log. It'll tell you why you're getting a 500